# Change body of method when is compiled for GWT client

Tags: java, gwt, reflection

I have a problem, I need to change body of method when this class is compiled for the gwt client. For server side I'm use reflection and I don't need this method for client side, so it can be empty. Here is the method:

```
public void check(Class<?> typeClass, Object object) {
    if (!typeClass.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass()))
        throw new RuntimeException("Check doesn't pass!");
}
```

So what I need is to check if the typeClass is a superclass or superinteface of object.

Comment: Why not using two implementations? One for the server side and one for the client both having the same interface but no implementation on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GWT.isClient()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#isClient%28%29) to check if the code is running on the client or server.

```
public void check(Class<?> typeClass, Object object) {
    if(!GWT.isClient()) {
        if (!typeClass.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass()))
            throw new RuntimeException("Check doesn't pass!");
        }
    }
}
```

As alternative, you can try to use [super-source](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModuleXml) in your gwt.xml file to provide a client only version of your class.